# u-boot-fw-utils_2019.07.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1' - RAUC(Yocto)

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, u-boot

I am integrating the software update mechanism **RAUC** in my yocto project for my device. I followed these [instructions in README file](https://github.com/rauc/meta-rauc) and I read the rauc documentation. Unfortunately I couldn't make it work and I got this error:  `u-boot-fw-utils_2019.07.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'`

The log.do_compile file content is :

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
NOTE: make -j 16 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0=/usr/src/debug/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0=/usr/src/debug/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now HOSTCC=gcc  -isystem/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/bsp/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 V=1 tx6q-1036_mfg_config tx6q-1036_config
set -e; \
for i in tx6q-1036_mfg_config tx6q-1036_config; do \
    make -f ./Makefile $i; \
done
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/kconfig tx6q-1036_mfg_config
scripts/kconfig/conf  --defconfig=arch/../configs/tx6q-1036_mfg_defconfig Kconfig
***
*** Can't find default configuration "arch/../configs/tx6q-1036_mfg_defconfig"!
***
scripts/kconfig/Makefile:128: recipe for target 'tx6q-1036_mfg_defconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [tx6q-1036_mfg_defconfig] Error 1
Makefile:516: recipe for target 'tx6q-1036_mfg_config' failed
make[1]: *** [tx6q-1036_mfg_config] Error 2
Makefile:498: recipe for target '__build_one_by_one' failed
make: *** [__build_one_by_one] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Execution of '/bsp/build/tmp/work/amr1-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/1_2019.07-r0/temp/run.do_compile.25964' failed with exit code 1:
set -e; \
for i in tx6q-1036_mfg_config tx6q-1036_config; do \
    make -f ./Makefile $i; \
done
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/kconfig tx6q-1036_mfg_config
scripts/kconfig/conf  --defconfig=arch/../configs/tx6q-1036_mfg_defconfig Kconfig
***
*** Can't find default configuration "arch/../configs/tx6q-1036_mfg_defconfig"!
***
scripts/kconfig/Makefile:128: recipe for target 'tx6q-1036_mfg_defconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [tx6q-1036_mfg_defconfig] Error 1
Makefile:516: recipe for target 'tx6q-1036_mfg_config' failed
make[1]: *** [tx6q-1036_mfg_config] Error 2
Makefile:498: recipe for target '__build_one_by_one' failed
make: *** [__build_one_by_one] Error 2
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

Anybody could help in this.

Comment: what `MACHINE` you are using?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM, it is a custom "amr1" `MACHINE` requires to  "Ka-Ro electronics TX6Q-1130" `MACHINE`

Comment: I would like to try the build process, can you provide the right steps that you did? I think it is related to the "amr1" bsp layer and not to meta-rauc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that, the problem was with `u-boot-fw-utils` in the karo-bsp **zeus** release, I upgraded to the **Hardknott** release and `u-boot-fw-utils` compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [meta-rauc-community](https://github.com/rauc/meta-rauc-community) project? In order to make Rauc work with your board in yocto, you either need to add the necessary meta-rauc-community layer or extend support to the board. There are some bbappends that u-boot uses in order to permit the use of Rauc.

To address your specific issue though, it appears as if the defconfig u-boot requires is missing. This error doesn't seem to be related to rauc as far as I can tell. Are you sure you're setting the correct `UBOOT_MACHINE` in your machine config file?

Comment: Yes, I took a look at the meta-rauc-community and I tried to do the same for my custom board. About my `MACHINE` it requires **tx6q-1036.conf** `MACHINE` from [karo-bsp](https://github.com/karo-electronics/karo-bsp) (Karo-electronics som) and in the **tx6q-1036.conf** there is `UBOOT_CONFIG` specified and if I do add `UBOOT_MACHINE` I get an error: `Nothing RPROVIDES 'u-boot-fw-utils' u-boot-fw-utils was skipped: You cannot use UBOOT_MACHINE and UBOOT_CONFIG at the same time`.

Comment: What is the specified `UBOOT_CONFIG`? Something is pointing to a defconfig that is either incorrectly named or doesn't exist.

Comment: `UBOOT_CONFIG[generic] = "tx6q-1036_config"`
`UBOOT_CONFIG[mfg] = "tx6q-1036_mfg_config"`
`UBOOT_CONFIG[noenv] = "tx6q-1036_noenv_config"`
`UBOOT_CONFIG[secure-boot] = "tx6q-1036_sec_config"`
They are just names which are not pointing to anything as I see.